# Java: why does DatagramSocket's `receive` method truncate messages?

Tags: java, udp

Coming from a C `socket()`/`recv()` background, the Java [DatagramSocket.receive](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive%28java.net.DatagramPacket%29) API seems a bit strange. Why does force the programmer to allocate a `DatagramPacket` large enough for the incoming data?

Comment: So, what is the behavior in C?

Comment: That is a good question… Up until now I had assumed that `recvfrom` would continue to return the remaining data, but experiments prove that I am mistaken. See comment on @Stephen C's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is based on a false premise.  In C, the signature for the `recv` syscall is:

```
ssize_t recv(int s, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

Note that you pass a pointer to a buffer, and the length of that buffer.  The manual entry then says:

> If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, excess bytes may be discarded depending on the type of socket the message is received from.

In other words, the C API expects the caller to allocate a "large enough" buffer, and *may* truncate messages that are longer ... just like Java does.

Comment: So, my system's man pages do *not* make it clear exactly when the excess bytes will be discarded… But on reflection it makes sense that, because UDP isn't streaming, it would not be sensible to try and store the unread portion of a datagram and return it on the next call to `recvfrom`… And a quick experiment proved this to be true.  Thanks for the help.